# Is it possible for a spark job on bluemix to access other users spark job files?

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

A common approach for connecting to third party systems from spark is to provide the credentials for the systems in a properties file that is passed to the spark script.  However, this raises some questions about security.

Is it possible for a spark job running on bluemix to access files from other users spark jobs?  I'm guessing that it was a design goal that this must not be possible, but it would be good to verify this.

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448179/is-it-possible-for-a-spark-job-on-bluemix-to-see-a-list-of-the-other-processes-o) to this one, but the other question focuses on the security of passing credentials to the spark script as arguments to the script.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031541/bluemix-spark-submit-how-to-secure-credentials-needed-by-my-scala-jar/37103272#37103272) asks a similar question to this one, but is asking for security best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Bluemix Apache Spark service, each provisioned spark service instance is a tenant. Each tenant is isolated from all other tenants. Spark jobs of a given tenant cannot access files or memory of any other tenant.